# Using MySQL REGEX to match repeating numbers in phone numbers

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I had a previous question using preg_replace but can't seem to get this to work using MySQL REGEX function. Basically, I have a database of phone numbers. For example:

```
8452100000
```

I want to be able to dynamically search for phone numbers like so:

```
2XX512YYYY
```

Where X and Y could be any digit, but each represents repetition of the same digit. I tried this so far and it's not working. I can get it to work with PHP `preg_match()`, but not with MySQL `REGEX()`. Can you see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE number REGEXP '^2[[:digit:]]\1{1}512[[:digit:]]\2{4}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\1` and `\2` will not work because MySQL doesn't support back-references to subgroups in regular expressions. You need to be explicit about what can match, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE number REGEXP '^2(00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99)512(0000|1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|6666|7777|8888|9999)'
```

This is clunky, but this is how it is until MySQL implements a Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE) engine, unless you want to install an extension.

Comment: I did that and still doesnt work. This is the number Im trying to find using that regex 2445121111 and nothing is coming back

Comment: Contrell I also switched {1} in the first group to {2} and still doesnt work. The field its in is a bigint. Does that matter?

Comment: Please see my edit; the last count should be `{3}` - you're double-counting the digits in that group (`1 + 4 = 5`, but you want `1 + 3 = 4`).

Comment: The fact that it's in a bigint shouldn't matter, but that's not the best way to store phone numbers. Also, if you want to tag someone in a comment, use `@` + the display name, like @EdCottrell. ("Contrell" is a misspelling and doesn't do anything to notify anyone that you have replied).

Comment: @John using http://www.phpliveregex.com/ to test Ed's regex returns the number itself and the repeated integers. An array with 3 elements for the number 2445121111

Comment: @EdCottrell I added the same that I thought was in your name. My bad. I tried it and still doesnt work. I guess Im doing something wrong. Doesnt make sense.

Comment: @D.Foley I can get this to work using php regex, but it wont work via the MySQL REGEXP query.

Comment: @John Did you try copying and pasting the exact query specified in my edited answer?

Comment: @edcottrell Yes, tried that as well as many other variations. Does it matter what type of database or character type it is in? Its INNODB with collation as  utf8_general_ci. You said bigint was not a good way of storing phone numbers, is there something I should change to make this regexp work? I can get it to work with php preg_match with easy, but mysql regexp nothing is working.

Comment: Please see my edit; I forgot MySQL does not currently support back-references.

Comment: @edcottrell That answered that headache. Dont know if I can translate someone searching 2XX512YYYY to the query you have in your answer. But there is like 400k rows in the db. Returning all the results each time then using php preg_match to go through the ones that match doesnt seem to be very optimal. Hmm... I appreciate the help.

Comment: @edcottrell Looks like I will just use an array and for each number of letters found I will replace it with that predefined search query you have in your example query. Thanks again!

Comment: Works for me:  `mysql> select '2445121111' regexp '^2(00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99)512(0000|1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|6666|7777|8888|9999)';`  --> `1`.